# To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a phpmailer that I took straight out of the phpmailer documents and suited it to what I needed.  So it should work.  Unfortunately, I'm getting the above error.  I've bought a web hosting package so that i could change the php.ini file by adding `always_populate_raw_post_data' = '-1'` to the file.  I'm still getting the above error.  Any ideas on how to fix this issue?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you attach the php.ini here?

Comment: Sure.  The php.ini file is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0VE48QS78T

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find it there

Answer (score 0):

Did you **restarted** your web server after saving the changes?

If you did, my guess would be that you edited a dummy `php.ini`.

You can use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and search for `loaded configuration file` to see where is the `php.ini` you need to edit.

Ask your hosting provider if they see that you've updated the file, they should be able to help furthermore.